# Generating XYZ tiles slow on QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, tiles

I'm new to the world of mapping and using QGIS. I need to render and create map tiles for the entire world using QGIS. However, the process of creating MBTILES is quite slow due to the large number of tiles (200 milion +) that need to be generated (zoom level is 19).

I suspect that this slowness is due to QGIS not utilizing GPU parallelization for tile rendering. Does anyone know if there are solutions available to generate these tiles using the GPU, or if there are alternative methods to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you need 19th zoom tiles for the whole world? I think even OSM does not render tiles at such a zoom in advance, they are generated on the fly when requested and left in the cache.

Comment: Performance is based on many factors, open your task manager and see if you can identify the bottleneck - It's probably you hard drive that's slowing it down. I  would not expect QGIS to use GPU resources unless you're rendering a 3d view or creating a fly-through video, there is a very limited set of instructions that are recognized by a GPU.

Comment: Could you please share your computer specifications?

Comment: @VsevolodTsukanov  yes i need it for a location based game that i will provide tiles to .

Comment: @MichaelStimson , i think you might be right, the bottleneck should be cause by the hard drive speed, i will check

Comment: @GIS ryzen 5 2400g, 16 gb ddr 2600 , barracuda hard disk , gtx 3060ti , is not a very powerlfull pc from a cpu prospective

Comment: I never used AMD before so I cannot comment much on that. In my opinion 16Gb is a bit at the lower limit especially if you have other services running in the background. We usually take a minimum of 32 Gb RAM. I suggest your try to test a subset of the data to check if the result is acceptable then run the entire dataset.

Comment: @GIS i will try using a remote desktop with better specs and see if that help.

Comment: Keep us updated so we can learn from your experience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147804/discussion-between-mezza-and-gis).